# ImportError: C extension: No module named 'parsing' not built

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, importerror, python-c-api

I have been trying to find a solution to this import error regarding the pandas library when it says no module named "parsing." Every library should be installed correctly from the interpreter and they are all the latest version.

This is what the console returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas._libs import (hashtable as _hashtable,
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\_libs\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from .tslib import iNaT, NaT, Timestamp, Timedelta, OutOfBoundsDatetime
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pxd", line 11, in init pandas._libs.tslib
  File "pandas\_libs\tslibs\conversion.pyx", line 40, in init pandas._libs.tslibs.conversion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parsing'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shaya/PycharmProjects/NEA/Main.py", line 4, in <module>
import pandas_datareader.data as data
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
from .data import (DataReader, Options, get_components_yahoo,
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\data.py", line 7, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.av.forex import AVForexReader
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\av\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from pandas_datareader.base import _BaseReader
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas_datareader\base.py", line 7, in <module>
import pandas.compat as compat
  File "C:\Users\shaya\PycharmProjects\NEA\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
"the C extensions first.".format(module))
ImportError: C extension: No module named 'parsing' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first.
```

All of the above tracebacks are from PyCharm.

OS: Windows.
I am using pip to install packages
Python version: 3.7.1, panda version: 0.23.4

Comment: I am using pip to install the packages as well as the inbuilt interpreter within PyCharm (sorry I forgot to mention that). And also, I tried running the above with cmd, but I'm not sure where exactly or how to run that.

Comment: Python is added to the path hence why I am installing the packages with pip and I did try running the above exactly how it was written in cmd, and it returns an error of "python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory", even though all packages have been installed correctly and with the latest upgrade.

Comment: When I enter python it comes up with the python shell in cmd and then it returns an invalid syntax error. But even then typing in the regular cmd will come up with that error in the previous comment.

Comment: I am using Python version 3.7.1, yes I was able to install pandas successfully as the end result was the 100% bar complete and the output of "pandas succesfully installed, and the pandas version installed is 0.23.4. It was working completely fine yesterday so I am struggling to find the problem or what I changed

Comment: Yes I just did it now and tried the process again but again the same error is being returned.

Comment: That is the problem - I do not think I have changed anything consciously, but I know I must have done something. Although I appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions and your patience with me, I will try to do a bit more research and try to resolve it myself. But as you said, I will most likely create a new environment

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and I will be sure to accept your summary.

Comment: Let me know if you get it working; we can do some more troubleshooting... The problem could also be PIP, you can also try to install pandas through conda.

Comment: I have the same problem described here. My code was working earlier today and all of a sudden, I am getting the same error: ImportError: C extension: No module named 'parsing' not built. If you want to import pandas from the source directory, you may need to run 'python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force' to build the C extensions first

Comment: I saw this on two computers yesterday. Are you using mcaffee antivirus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have python added to path? To test this; open a cmd and type `python`. If it is on your path, you should see the version of python you are running (Assuming you are using a windows machine). If this is the case, you can simply run the command after you checked this. If not, please navigate to the location where Python is installed, open `python.exe` and try to run the command `python setup.py build_ext --inplace --force`

If this doesn't work, you should try to re-install pandas by `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pandas`

If this also fails you could also go rigourous, and simply create a new environment and install pandas there. Sidenote: It is probably better to install pandas by using conda package manager, Pandas has portions of its code written in C to make it run faster. If you tried to install pandas manually you would need to build it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem under the same circumstances. I went through the code of some of the pandas files and saw that there is indeed a module named 'parsing' in the tslib folder of my pandas directory, yet for some reason it's not able to call it. I just reinstalled python and now it's working for me. If you find any other alternative, please let me know.